# Is there anything similar to binfmt-support on mac OS X?

Tags: macos

What I wish to know is whether there is something similar to binfmt-support on mac.

I have a nacl binary executable and I wish to make mac aware of the executable format so thatI can run this executable from command prompt directly.

I have seen people using binfmt-support on linux to achieve this.

Just to explain what I want in more simple terms - Say I have a.nexe file. I can run this file on mac terminal with command "../tools/sel_ldr_x86_32 -B ../tools/irt_core_x86_32.nexe a.nexe"

Instead of this big command, I wish to simply run it like "./a.nexe" and my shell file should then get invoked which would eventually call the command like "../tools/sel_ldr_x86_32 -B ../tools/irt_core_x86_32.nexe a.nexe"

Answer (score 1):

If the file itself is binary, so you can not add a #! to the start of the file, then so far as I know you only have one option; create an alias for the command line in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
alias nacl='/path/to/sel_ldr_x86_32 -B /path/to/irt_core_x86_32.nexe'
```

which would then let you type `nacl a.nexe` at the command line.

NOTE: You will want to use absolute paths in your alias for this to work correctly.